# A few odd things in a tcpdump capture for a database replication stream

Tags: sockets, tcp, wireshark, tcpdump

I'm trying to resolve the following performance problem. There is a database which is synchronously replicated to a remote location via TCP. Currently, everything works great. But it's being migrated to new hardware, and a test load shows that everything slows down roughly by a factor of 2. Basically, the current setup supports sustained transfer rates of 200-300 MB/s whereas the new one gets 100-150MB/s at best, and it's not good enough for us.

There is nothing obviously wrong from the database side. Database instrumentation says that the source database is busy sending data on the network (by large chunks, tens of MB at a time), and the destination one is busy receiving it on the network. So I'm looking at the TCP packet capture in Wireshark and I notice a few things that look a bit odd in the new setup -- see a sample below.

AFAIK the window scaling factor is 7 for this conversation so receive window gets a x128 factor which means most of the time it's not a limiting factor.

First of all, most of the time there is only 1 packet in flight per every ACK which is not the case for the existing setup where I can see multiple bursts of tens of outgoing packets. Is this Nagle algorithm in action or something else? It's supposed to be off (there is a tcp nodelay option on the application level) but it's still a bit suspicious.

Second, I don't understand the timings. It's almost as if something is controlling the rate of outgoing packets and keeps it roughly to 1 packet every 50 us (sometimes a bit more, sometimes a bit less), rather than leaving within a couple of microseconds after getting an ACK. Could there be some sort of burst control in place or am I imagining things?

Third, segment size. Most of segments are 8kB as compared to existing setup where they are 64kB. We experimented with the application settings but we can't seem to be able to make a difference -- 64kB segments are there, but they are rare. Is there a way in Linux to strongly encourage larger segments?

```
36  2022-09-01 15:02:45.267111  192.168.240.122 192.168.240.115 TCP 8210    45508 → 1600 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2162935757 Ack=3197136358 Win=6166 Len=8156
37  2022-09-01 15:02:45.267115  192.168.240.115 192.168.240.122 TCP 54      1600 → 45508 [ACK] Seq=3197136358 Ack=2162943913 Win=24525 Len=0
38  2022-09-01 15:02:45.267162  192.168.240.122 192.168.240.115 TCP 8210    45508 → 1600 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2162943913 Ack=3197136358 Win=6166 Len=8156
39  2022-09-01 15:02:45.267166  192.168.240.115 192.168.240.122 TCP 54      1600 → 45508 [ACK] Seq=3197136358 Ack=2162952069 Win=24525 Len=0
40  2022-09-01 15:02:45.267212  192.168.240.122 192.168.240.115 TCP 8210    45508 → 1600 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2162952069 Ack=3197136358 Win=6166 Len=8156
41  2022-09-01 15:02:45.267215  192.168.240.115 192.168.240.122 TCP 54      1600 → 45508 [ACK] Seq=3197136358 Ack=2162960225 Win=24525 Len=0
42  2022-09-01 15:02:45.267261  192.168.240.122 192.168.240.115 TCP 8210    45508 → 1600 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2162960225 Ack=3197136358 Win=6166 Len=8156
43  2022-09-01 15:02:45.267265  192.168.240.115 192.168.240.122 TCP 54      1600 → 45508 [ACK] Seq=3197136358 Ack=2162968381 Win=24525 Len=0
44  2022-09-01 15:02:45.267313  192.168.240.122 192.168.240.115 TCP 8210    45508 → 1600 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2162968381 Ack=3197136358 Win=6166 Len=8156
45  2022-09-01 15:02:45.267318  192.168.240.115 192.168.240.122 TCP 54      1600 → 45508 [ACK] Seq=3197136358 Ack=2162976537 Win=24525 Len=0
46  2022-09-01 15:02:45.267342  192.168.240.122 192.168.240.115 TCP 8210    45508 → 1600 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2162976537 Ack=3197136358 Win=6166 Len=8156
47  2022-09-01 15:02:45.267346  192.168.240.115 192.168.240.122 TCP 54      1600 → 45508 [ACK] Seq=3197136358 Ack=2162984693 Win=24525 Len=0
48  2022-09-01 15:02:45.267391  192.168.240.122 192.168.240.115 TCP 8210    45508 → 1600 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2162984693 Ack=3197136358 Win=6166 Len=8156
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**Update**: I've shared packet capture files on sender and receiver sides for both current setup and old setup at https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ktBDjRHOUCfia1kTfdVIQdS-Q1k4B3qn

**Update2**: I've written a blog entry about this investigation for those interested: https://savvinov.com/2022/09/20/use-of-packet-capture-and-other-advanced-tools-in-network-issues-troubleshooting/

Best regards,
Nikolai

Comment: It would seem that you're capturing on the receiving side, judging by the < 60 byte ACK packets, so the receiver is taking ~4us to process the incoming packets and send an ACK.  So the time between the ACK and the next chunk of data from the sender also includes the round-trip delay.  

Can you post a pair of sample capture files somewhere (dropbox, drive, cloudshark, ...) - 1 file containing the TCP flow for the old system and 1 for the new system so that the 2 can be compared? Please ensure that the TCP 3-way handshake is also captured so the window size and scaling factors will be known.

Comment: I've uploaded extracts from the new system's capture to Google Drive, you can download them with the link below:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ktBDjRHOUCfia1kTfdVIQdS-Q1k4B3qn?usp=sharing

I'll try to do the same for the old system, but I don't have the 3-way handshake captured there so the window scaling information will be missing there.

Best regards,
  Nikolai

Comment: OK, those files are rather large, contain multiple TCP streams and don't contain the 3-way handshake either.  If you can't get the 3-way handshake, maybe you could at least isolate the exact TCP stream of interest and only include a small subset of packets, perhaps 1000 or so should suffice.  My machine is just too slow to filter and work with such large capture files very effectively.

Comment: It's not an easy task to keep the files small while retaining all the characteristic patterns (and the fact that the original files are 1GB big which doesn't make things any easier! my Wireshark isn't lightning fast, either...). 

I'll try to produce something better, but meanwhile please keep in mind that the window scaling factor is 7 as I reported in my original post, and the vast majority of the packets in the pcap are from 192.168.240.123 <-> 192.168.24.115 conversation which is the one we are interested in.

Comment: Hi Christopher, 

I've added four files to the same folder on Google Drive, you can recognise them by "filtered" in the names. Unfortunately they are still a bit big (about 50MB each) but at least I got rid of other conversations as you requested and made sure the handshake was on (for the new setup capture; for the old one it's not possible to provide it). May I suggest editcap if file size is still an issue. 

Let me know if you can see any clues as to what is the main limiting factor for the throughput in the new setup. 

Thanks!

Best regards,
  Nikolai

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a definitive explanation for you.  One possible idea I was considering was that perhaps there's a mistake in the window size calculation, so instead of the window size being multiplied by 128 (2^7), it's incorrectly only being multiplied by 7 so you end up with a far smaller window size than what is actually available.  

If this isn't the problem, then I would recommend posting your question over at https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/, where there are usually a lot more packet analysis experts hanging around to help.  Good luck!

Comment: In addition to capturing just that stream, you should be able to configure wireshark to capture only the headers and that will greatly reduce the file size as well as help keep user data private; grab source and destination side pcaps; get from start of connection to first instance of issue; wireshark also lets you print the pcap with hex)to a txt file--post that (use "..." to reduce size); add the linux/<yourOS> tag to this question-- trouble shooting on Linux/OS side makes sense; I think TCP has q congestion window in addition to buffer sizes; there are TCP options that might be a factor too

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't find answers to all of my questions, I found the ones that mattered most.

It turned out that the TCP stack was sending data in 8kB segments because the "application" send it that way to it. By "application" I mean the replication software (Oracle Data Guard) that picked up a stream of database changes on the source database and wrote it to the remote standby.

So eventually I traced tcp_sendmsg using BCC trace.py utility and found that its segment size argument was about 8kB (8156 bytes to be more specific). Then I traced the network stack on the "application" level, forcing the connection to be re-established during the tracing, and it turned out to be that the parameter controlling the size of the transmission (SDU or session data unit) was supposed to be 64kB in settings, but in fact the new connection was using a smaller value, 8kB.

Further research showed that there was a number of oddities around the way this parameter is set, and also that the documentation around it was inaccurate.

When the correct way to set the value was found by trial and error, the throughput became immediately much better and all the bottlenecks that bothered us disappeared.

Best regards,
Nikolai

Comment: Thanks for following up.  Many issues just fall into an abbys. That's interesting.  If you have the time and inclination, please provide more details.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'm currently writing a blog post on the topic, should be able to post it in a few days. I will try to remember to provide a link here!